# How can I receive money on PayPal without giving a country ID? How can I change PayPal nationality?

Tags: account-management, paypal

I made a PayPal account 8 months ago and signed up with another nationality mistakenly (choosing nationality before the sign up page at the time wasn't clear and many cities all over the world share my city name; I'm not sure how I signed up but I ended up with US nationality) and I linked a MasterCard. When I received a payment from a freelancing site about a couple weeks ago, I tried taking the money on the MasterCard and it didn't work. So I tried linking my Visa with the same billing address as the MasterCard and it isn't the right address so it gives me errors. I can't add the right address as the nationality is set to US. So

- I can't receive the money on a card
- I can't accept the money on the account and use to buy any product online as I don't have any document to prove I'm a resident of the US
- I can't send the money to a new account I made linked with a Visa

Will the money will be in `waiting` status forever? Can I do anything about it?

Answer (score -1):

Changing your "nationality" is not an option for a PayPal account. Expected course of action is to close the account and open a new one with new nationality.

> Please note that in order to change the nationality, you'll have to
> close the existing PayPal account and then create a new one and
> selecting the nationality during the sign-up process.
>
> Before you close your account please remove your financial details.
>
> ### Removing your financial details:
>
> - go to **Profile**
> - select **My Money**
> - depending on what information
>   you want to remove, click **Update** in the relevant section
> - on the
>   next page, select the information you want to remove and click **Remove**
>
> ### Closing your old PayPal account:
>
> - log into your PayPal account at [**www.paypal.com**](http://www.paypal.com)
> - click **Profile** near
>   the top of the page
>   select **My Settings**
> - in the **Account Type**
>   section, click **Close account** and follow the instructions
>
> After you close your account, any transactions that are in progress
> are canceled.
>
> ### Creating a new PayPal account:
>
> - go to **[www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com)**
> - click **Sign Up** at the top of the page
> - select
>   your country or region and your language
> - select the type of account
>   you want to create, and then click **Get Started**
> - enter your
>   information, and then click **Agree and Create Account**
>
> After you have confirmed your email address, you can use your new
> account.
>
> We recommend that you add a credit card that was issued by a bank in
> the same country as the country on your PayPal account.
>
> @PayPal Support

Comment: This is just a copy paste . I'm asking how can i send this money to the new account ?